# Prepend to Simply Expanded Variable

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am working with some MPI code that I need to run with `mpirun`.

I am using an already existing shell script and I want to prepend to an already existing line.

So the dream is:

```
app=mpirun $(app)
```

I know it is possible to append to a variable using +=, but can I prepend?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `app` should become (or remain) a simply expanded variable, then the following would be enough:

```
app := mpirun $(app)
```